# Core Location in Swift

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager, ios8

This is sample code. `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` key in Info.plist installed. All work fine - program receives the coordinates.... displays them.....

And it continues to update them permanently! In the case of the iOS simulator - it is not critical, but in the case of a real application it is very quickly drain the battery. How to make an application launched Core Location, received location, and got shut down Core Location?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var locLabel: UILabel
@IBOutlet var latLabel: UILabel
@IBOutlet var lonLabel: UILabel

var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func locButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:AnyObject[]) {
    println("locations = \(locationManager)")
    var latValue = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
    var lonValue = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude
    latLabel.text = String(latValue)
    lonLabel.text = String(lonValue)
    locLabel.text = "success"
}
```

}

Comment: In didUpdateLocations, you can call stopUpdatingLocation() after you are satisfied with the current location's accuracy/timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not much concern about high level of accuracy then you should consider `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` instead of `startUpdatingLocation`. It will really make a big difference in battery draining.

This method is more appropriate for the majority of applications that just need an initial user location fix and need updates only when the user moves a significant distance. This interface delivers new events only when it detects changes to the device’s associated cell towers, resulting in less frequent updates and significantly lower power usage.

For more detail you can take a look over [CLLocationManager Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges)